# C2D permission error

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions

I'm building an app and I want to send push notifications to the users of this app, so I use the `PushBots` services.

In their guide, they say to put these permissions in the manifest:

```
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="com.example.sampleapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.sampleapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"    />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive dataf message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

But in the new `permission request` system, I have to request every single permission.

So now I'm asking these permissions in my app:

-location permissions (I use map activity).

-accounts permissions (PushBots said it is required).

I've tried to run my app, and this is the error I get:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.giladneiger.haerev.permission.C2D_MESSAGE`

How can I request a permission for this? There is no option for it, and my app will request so many permissions that the user will lose his patience for it.

What do I have to do with this error?

Comment: Where is this package - com.giladneiger.haerev? What is your application package name ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your package name com.giladneiger.haerev instead of com.example.sampleapp in  the lines

Comment: Ok, and than I need to request permission specificly for this like here? : http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: No need. It will be granted at install time. Just add the permission and uses-permission lines with your package name

Comment: <permission android:name="com.giladneiger.haerev.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.giladneiger.haerev.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"    />

Comment: ok, and do I have to request permission for the `GET_ACCOUNTS`? Because they said "GCM requires a Google account".

Comment: You should still request for GET_ACCOUNTS if PushBot needs it. If you are just using GCM, I think it is no longer needed.

Comment: Ok, is the PushBot actually needed? Can't I just use GCM? I got really confused about all this thing. I just want to send to my app users a push notification sometimes.... How should I do it in the best way? What do you recommend me to do?

Comment: Sorry, haven't really tried PushBot. In our projects, we just use plain GCM but with our own GCM server

Comment: Do you have a good tutorial to use plain GCM without PushBot?